# Join tables hibernate + group by

Tags: java, hibernate, detachedcriteria

I need to do this query with Java + Hibernate.

```
SELECT 
    table2.id,
    COUNT(table2.id) AS count
FROM
  table1 
    JOIN table2
       ON table1.fk_tb2 = table2.id  --many2one
GROUP BY
   table2.id
```

I would use DetachedCriteria class.....how can i do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using projections like this:

```
Criteria table1Crit = session.createCriteria("table1");
Criteria table2Crit = table1Crit.createCriteria("table2", Criteria.INNER_JOIN);
table2Crit.setProjection( Property.forName("id").count() );
```

Answer (score -3):

use your query with `createNativeQuery` method

Comment: this would defeat the purpose of using hibernate, if you resorted to native queries for such simple stuff.

Comment: well find the answer and let me know.