# How to do LEFT JOIN with GROUP BY in Hibernate criteria?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I am trying to convert the following native SQL query into Hibernate java code. Looked all the questions in SO, but didnt help

```
SELECT TableB.username,COUNT(TableA.userId) AS NumberOfOrders 
FROM TableA
    LEFT JOIN TableB
    ON TableA.userId=TableB.Id
    GROUP BY userId;
```

What I have tried is

```
criteria=hibernate.createCriteria(TableA.class);
criteria.setFetchMode("TableB",FetchMode.JOIN);
ProjectionList projectionList = Projections.projectionList();
projectionList.add(Projections.groupProperty("userId"));
projectionList.add(Projections.rowCount());
criteria.setProjection(projectionList);
```

But It didnt work. How to fix this? How can I convert that SQL into Java code? Please give me some suggestions

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11148277/895532) to a previous answered question might be helpful for your case, with a couple quick change to the join type, fields, etc.

Comment: @king14nyr I have tried that in the link, but it says (org.hibernate.MappingException) org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: TableB. But I have the entity. I am not using detachedcriteria.